# Error in creatinng a field in the table

Tags: mysql, sql

I have problem in creation a field name `staus` which `type-BOOLEAN`. and length is 1.

When I press the go button then this Massage Arrived

```
SQL query:

ALTER TABLE `abcd` ADD `status` BOOLEAN( 1 ) BINARY NOT NULL DEFAULT NULL

MySQL said: Documentation
#1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '(1) BINARY NOT NULL DEFAULT NULL' at line 1
```

I can't solve the problem. I don't know where the error occurring.

Please Help me to solve the problem.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
ALTER TABLE `abcd` 
ADD COLUMN `status` BIT NOT NULL DEFAULT 0
```

1. If you want to create only a single bit field use `BIT`. You had 2 data types in your statement.
2. Your default value was `null` but you don't want to allow that: `NOT NULL`. Use `0` as default value instead.

Comment: why can't i use Boolean for in this field? @juergen

Comment: `boolean` and `bit` are the same in MySQL. The problem was that you used **2** data types: `boolean` and `BINARY`.

Answer (score 3):

The correct syntax for [`ALTER TABLE`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/alter-table.html) requires `COLUMN` after `ADD`

```
ALTER TABLE `abcd` ADD COLUMN ...
```

Answer (score 0):

For MySQL 5.0.3 and higher, you can use BIT. The manual says:

As of MySQL 5.0.3, the BIT data type is used to store bit-field values. A type of BIT(M) enables storage of M-bit values. M can range from 1 to 64.

Otherwise, according to the MySQL manual you can use bool and boolean which are at the moment aliases of tinyint(1):

Bool, Boolean: These types are synonyms for TINYINT(1). A value of zero is considered false. Non-zero values are considered true.